# Change current step line background color

Tags: qt, debugging, qt-creator

Is it possible to change the background color of the line at which the debugger has currently stopped?

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, that's just the *current line*, either while editing or debugging.

Answer (score 0):

sure, in the qt creator go to editor and enable the "Highlight current line" option

[image]

Comment: I don't mean for the current cursor line to be highlighted, but for the debugger stop line to be highlighted (while debugging)